# Disable Google Doodle games

Tags: google-search, google-doodle

My kid needs to do homework on PC (*Windows + Chrome*).

However he keeps getting distracted by Google Doodle games. I would like to disable / block these games. A simple solution like "change this setting within Chrome" would work (*the kid's too young to figure out a work around*).

[This](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33920/304826) post has a few solutions, but none really works for me.

1. A different browser than Chrome is not an option (*my family is locked into Chrome*)
2. I prefer not to install more applications (*add-ins, extensions or anything*)
3. Disabling JavaScript for all sites works, but kills every other website too. I tried disabling JavaScript just for google.com, but that didn't really do anything.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

##### No longer a flag-based switch

There used to be a way to disable it using `chrome://flags/` (Chrome Experimental Features)  however that flag removed by Google.

##### Disabling JavaScript is Not a Solution

Disabling JavaScript would "kneecap" access to many sites and also have a negative impact on much of the browsing behavior you likely take for granted.

> I ***prefer*** not to install more applications (add-ins, extensions or anything)

##### You *need* to install software

Chrome does not natively provide the functionality you seek, ergo to achieve this functionality you will need to modify the code in some way.

If you are going down the path of bending Chrome to your will, you will need to install custom script such as an extension.  Browser extensions are a very common method used to modify Chrome in order to add or remove functionality.

[Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) extensions could modify two behaviors to allow Chrome to behave as you prefer.

---

##### Behavior you need modified:

1. ***Force*** Chrome to always use Google's `default logo`
   [Chrome Extensions Search  **>**  hide doodles](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/hide%20doodles?_category=extensions)
2. ***Redirect*** all `new tabs` to a custom URL
   [Chrome Extensions Search  **>**  new tab redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/new%20tab%20redirect?_category=extensions)

##### Is it safe?

You might like to read this article by Lifehacker "[How to Know If a Google Chrome Extension Is Safe](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-know-if-a-google-chrome-extension-is-safe-to-use-1848824700)" about assessing extensions in the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions).

##### Extensions you can try

*You can add and remove extensions, so if these don't meet your needs you might try others.*

- Doodle Blocker for Google
  **Chrome:**  [webstore/Doodle Blocker for Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/doodle-blocker-for-google/jfcifhfgpkjakpfmilfkfjnfabgmhpnl)
  **Github:**    [cansinacarer/Doodle-Blocker-for-Google](https://github.com/cansinacarer/Doodle-Blocker-for-Google)
- New Tab Redirect
  **Chrome:** [webstore/New Tab Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-changer/occbjkhimchkolibngmcefpjlbknggfh)

##### The Alternative

Bending Chrome to your will necessitates accepting the risk and overhead associated with selecting, installing, and testing extensions. The alternative is to use the Chrome browser as designed.